# Using numeric column in dataframe within formula in R

Tags: dataframe, csv, formula, linguistics

I am a newbie and trying to do a transformation from one unit to another using the numbers that make up a column in a dataframe that I'm using.

The formula is `[(26.81x)/(1960+x)]-0.53`.

I've tried a few different things. It gave me the error "non-numeric argument to binary operator" even though it has determined that the class of that column is "numeric.

It would also be ideal if I could create the new column within the dataframe using the new values.

Can anyone help? I'm sure this seems very basic.

Here's the code I tried using:

```
df = read.csv("df" ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
freq = data.frame(as.numeric(df$column))
((26.81*"freq")/(1960+"freq"))-0.53
```